# What do the striped grey areas in the chrome CPU timeline mean?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image: CPU Timeline]

There's significant CPU usage shown here, but no reason given. Timeline taken from Android Chrome v51.

Comment: This is on the Timeline panel, correct?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Grey** means that DevTools is aware of the activity but doesn't know the identity of it.

**Striped** means activity that is off of the main thread.

So, **grey and striped** means unidentified activity that is not occurring in the main thread.

**Gold and striped** means script activity off the main thread. This is typically a worker, though ScriptStreamer can show up too. (ScriptStreamer wasn't really instrumented well before Chrome 77.) Collapse the "Main Thread" section to see what's beneath it.

**Gold, purple, green and striped** means script & rendering activity off the main thread. That's most likely coming from [out-of-process iframes](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/site-isolation). Again, you can collapse the "Main Thread" section to more easily explore the other threads.

---

If you're seeing lots of gray in the overview (striped or not), it indicates DevTools isn't showing you details on the activity. In this case, you can file a bug to provide more information. [Capture a full trace](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool) (using `chrome://tracing`) and open a ticket on [crbug.com](https://crbug.com) so that DevTools team can diagnose more.

You can also [turn on hidden DevTools experiments](https://hackernoon.com/hidden-experimental-features-in-chrome-devtools-2ae93b11b628) and then select "Timeline: show all events" to have the flamechart show everything it knows about.

Comment: Hi Kayce, sorry I forgot to follow up on this. I recently went back to look at this, and determined that it was a CSS-keyframe animation that caused the unidentified activity. I removed the animation and all of the activity went away.

Comment: Thanks @RyanCheu I forwarded the info to the team. Can you create a reproducible sample?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o1j1q03r/show/ should reproduce the issue. Visiting this page in Chrome on Android shows http://i.imgur.com/7yqqQxr.png

Comment: would you happen to know the answer to another perf dev tool related question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470393/what-is-the-time-thats-shown-in-a-column-next-to-javascript-in-the-chrome-devel

Comment: Would you see these when only out-of-process iframes have activity while the profile has been taken, but that same activity would be mixed in with the rest (i.e., no stripes) otherwise?

Comment: Can I suggest to include this information in the documentation, it highly valuable? (or if it already is, why is it so hard to find? :) )

Reference: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference

Comment: RyanCheu, same here, CSS animation is causing 30% cpu load, also when the page is in background (not visible). this is on a cheap laptop (no GPU acceleration)