# Website significant slow down and performance Timeline showing high CPU usage on grey area

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently investigating on a performance issue. Here is how the timeline looks like. (Timeline taken on Chrome v59)

[image: Performance Timeline]

[image: Performance Timeline Summary]

From the timeline, there is a very high CPU usage on **Other** (grey area) but there are not much of **Scripting**, **Rendering** or **Painting** happening. The website is slowing down significantly.

From the answer shown here [What do the striped grey areas in the chrome CPU timeline mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001857/what-do-the-striped-grey-areas-in-the-chrome-cpu-timeline-mean)

> Grey means that DevTools is aware of the activity but doesn't know the identity of it. Striped means activity that is off of the main thread.
>   So, grey and striped means unidentified activity that is not occurring in the main thread.

Does it means it is not something that caused by my code? What is the possible reasons that we are seeing these results?

Comment: Enable chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments and restart the browser, then open devtools, then its settings, then Experiments, then press the Shift key 6 times (close and ignore any OS dialogs), enable `Show all events`, `Show all processes`, `V8 runtime call stats` and redo the recording.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks for the tip, I am seeing more information now. Unfortunately, I do not have a way to reproduce the issue, have to redo the recording when the issue happens again. I do have the previous timeline profile results though, and I am seeing result like [this](http://imgur.com/a/uRdXm) on chrome://tracing/
and [this](http://imgur.com/a/61dc4) particular task is taking more time than usual. Any hint? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: On normal condition, it will only take about 3 ms. Here is a rough comparison http://imgur.com/a/uRdXm

Comment: Are you using service workers or web workers?

Comment: Not using service workers or web workers, but i have an open Websocket connection for some live update operations.