# What is the time that's shown in a column next to Javascript in the Chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

It clearly has something to do with how long the function takes, what specifically does it represent? Ex. if the function was called multiple times during execution, what value is used?

Comment: I've never seen that. Did you enable profiling?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, this is with profiling enabled. Feature was announced here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/devtools-digest, but there's no detail on what it means.

Comment: My guess is it's the total time spent in that function. So if it's called multiple times, it's the combined times.

Comment: Hm, it seems to be something like that, but still a little strange.

For example, in this test I ran http://i.imgur.com/E3Q0a5s.png, it doesn't make sense that only 8.8ms out of 2759 were spent on the if statement. (This function executed 3 times). I also expected 2759 to be closer to 3000.

Comment: Maybe `new Date()` is super slow.

Comment: I did another test to test the speed of new Date() vs getTime(), using console.timing(), and new Date() is only about 10x faster than getTime() on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed supposed to be a breakdown of the total time spent on each line.

If a line is called multiple times, the value you see is the combined time spent in total for that line.

I agree that the line-by-line breakdown does yield some strange results sometimes. I'll look into that more.

Update: DevTools team says that the profiling comes from V8. So their response was just "this is how V8 attributes the time spent." I'll see if I can get a V8 guy or girl in here to discuss further.

Comment: Thanks for the response! For lines without numbers, are those lines unmeasured/insignificant, or are they merged into one of the times nearby?

This might be the strange results referenced earlier, but in the example I posted (http://i.imgur.com/E3Q0a5s.png), I'm still confused how to interpret the 21ms for the function and 2759ms for the while loop. Is the 2759ms the time spent inside the while loop, or executing the while checks themselves (and similarly for the function time)?